# Duplicate case closed and its case comment need to be added to previous case

Tags: apex, trigger, case

can we achieve this scenario ?any help is very much appreciated.

Duplicate  case closed and its case comment need to be added to original case???

Some Code written :

```
trigger CasecommentTrigger on CaseComment (before insert) {         
 Set<String> caseSubs = new Set<String>();        
  Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();       
 List<Case> listCases = new List<Case>();        
List<Case> listUpdateCases = new List<Case>();       
 List<CaseComment> listCaseComm = new List<CaseComment>();       
 List<CaseComment> listInsertCaseComm = new List<CaseComment>();        
Map<String, Id> mapCasSubId = new Map<String, Id>();       
 Map<Id, CaseComment> mapCaseIdCasComm = new Map<Id, CaseComment>();                       
 if(CommonVariables.caseRepeatCheck) {        
CommonVariables.caseRepeatCheck = false;        
Case cas1 = [SELECT Id, Subject,status, Description FROM Case WHERE id=:trigger.new[0].parentid];        
listCases = [SELECT Id, Subject, Description FROM Case WHERE Subject=:cas1.subject and id!=:cas1.id and status='New'];
        system.debug('@@@'+listcases.size());        
listCaseComm = [SELECT Id, CommentBody, ParentId FROM CaseComment WHERE ParentId =:trigger.new[0].id];          
  if(listCases.size() > 0) {                 
for(Case cas : listCases) {        
 CaseComment cm=new CaseComment();        
 cm.commentbody=trigger.new[0].CommentBody();        
 cm.ParentId=cas.id;         
listInsertCaseComm.add(cm);       
 }                
 insert listInsertCaseComm;                       
 }                
cas1.status='Closed';       
 update cas1; }       
}
```

Comment: Any tried codes?

Comment: Your approach needs to be rethought. The trigger should be on Case afterUpdate. The trigger should filter for Cases that are closed and duplicate, then collect all children CaseComments and insert them as children to the original Case. Be sure to bulkify it

Comment: @crop1645:Im Newbie ,can u plz help me out with the code.

Answer (score 1):

OK, nikkey

Let's assume that when a Case is closed, that there is:

- a picklist field Closed_reason__c with one of the values = 'Duplicate'
- a text field Duplicate_of_case_Number__c

and you have made both fields are required on the Case Close layout

```
trigger CaseClosed on Case (after update) {
  // 1 - collect up all cases closed as duplicate
  Set<ID> csDupIdSet = new Set<ID> ();  // cases that are dups
  Set<String> csOrigCaseNumberSet = new Set<String> ();  // caseNumbers of the original cases
  for (Case cs : Trigger.new)
    if (cs.isClosed && cs.closed_reason__c == 'Duplicate'  && duplicate_of_case_number__c != null) {
        csDupIdSet.add(cs.id); // for bulkification
        csOrigCaseNumberSet.add(cs.duplicate_of_case_number__c); // for bulkification
    }
  // trigger doesn't have context of caseComments so we have to query for them
  Map<ID,Case> csIdToCaseWCommentListMap = new Map<ID,Case> (
                                                  [select id, duplicate_of_case_number__c, 
                                                    (select id, commentBody from caseComments)
                                                   from case where id IN: csDupIdSet]);

  // 2 - Collect all 'original' cases and map by CaseNumber
  Map<String,Case> csNumberToCaseMap = new Map<String,Case>();
  for (Case cs: [select id,caseNumber from Case where caseNumber IN :csOrigCaseNumberSet])
       csNumberToCaseMap.put(caseNumber,cs);

  // 3 -- 'copy' over the duplicate case's comments to the original case
  CaseComment[] cscInsList = new List<CaseComment> ();
  for (Case cs :  csIdToCaseWCommentListMap.values()) {
    ID csOrigId = csNumberToCaseMap.get(cs.caseNumber).id;  // find orig case by caseNumber
    for (CaseComment csc : cs.caseComments)
         cscinsList.add(new caseComment body=csc.body, parentId = csOrigId));

  insert cscInsList;   // try catches, decision on optAllOrNone omitted for clarity; bulkified
  }
}
```

I'm not going to do all your work for you but this should give you the idea of how a bulkified trigger should work that copies caseComments from one case to another.

Comment: I have created  both the fields as suggested,i do get Errors as :Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: duplicate_of_case_number__c at line 6 column 62,Error: Compile Error: AND operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions at line 6 column 24,Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: caseNumber__c at line 19 .

Comment: nikkey -- sorry, code is without warranties - I fixed line 6 (should have been `==` not `=` in the comparison operator).  The solution is to get you thinking about how to solve the problem and you should adapt it to your own use case (for example, I took one way of determining the duplicate where the case closer identifies the duplicate case number).  The take aways are the multiple passes to collect the relevant cases w/ comments to copy, collect the target cases to copy into, then construct the casecomments for copy and do the DML - all in a bulkified manner

Comment: :I did tried implementing necessary changes but stil it is not identifying the duplicate case and getting closed by adding their casecomment to the original case.

Comment: Nikkey - go back to your original post and update it with the current code you are using, and extract of the debug log for a given test run. You might also add in debug statements to understand the values of the variables at each step of the way